# Требуется оптимизация под 10'' планшеты. Рекомендация google play

Tags: android, google-play

Как лечится сообщение при публикации приложения?
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

ps. Скрин для 10'' загружен. Папка values-sw720dp присутствует.

Comment: сообщение лечится скрытием рекомендации. Насколько я знаю, эта "рекомендация" появляется для абсолютно всех приложений.

Comment: Наблюдашка: приложения, изначально созданные в андроид студио такого сообщения не получают

Answer (score 1):

Может поможет, добавить в манифест это

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

values-sw720dp
а точно достаточно, может еще смотрят на layout-xx600dp - xx720dp